# psycopg2 - Error missing data for field "id"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I am importing a CSV file to postgres and there is no unique column in the dataset. I want to add a serial ID field to uniquely identify each record as its inserted into the table.

I have created a sequence and added an ID field to the table structure before triggering the import:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS serial;
CREATE TABLE my_tbl (
    fname    varchar(100),
    lname    varchar(100),
    company  varchar(200),
    id       integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('serial')
);
```

I run this code to import the CSV which has data for fname, lname and company:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=user, password=pwd)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.copy_expert("copy {} from STDIN CSV HEADER QUOTE '\"'".format(table_name), file)
cur.execute("commit;")
```

However, I get an error saying I'm missing data for field "id". I assume under the hood psycopg2 is matching the schemas of the CSV and PG table to validate the COPY before it attempts the insert. A regular insert would succeed as the id field would be populated with a value from the SEQ.

How can I add a unique id field to each record that's copied from the CSV to the PG table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. You can specify columns of the target table in the COPY command, e.g.:

```sql
COPY my_tbl(fname, lname, company) FROM STDIN CSV HEADER QUOTE '"'
```

Alternatively, create the table without the `id` primary key, import the csv data and only then add the primary key:

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_tbl ADD id serial PRIMARY KEY;
```

---

Not related. You do not have to create a sequence for a serial column, let Postgres do this for you:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_tbl (
    fname    varchar(100),
    lname    varchar(100),
    company  varchar(200),
    id       serial PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then the system knows the relationship between the table and the sequence. (Also, `serial` is not the best name for a sequence, how do you name the next one when you need it?)

Comment: thanks @klin, is it possible to dynamically populate the column list based on what the headers in the CSV file are?

Comment: Not automatically in Postgres, but it should be easy in Python, just read the first line of the file and respectively format the command.

Comment: Ok, that was what I had done in the meantime so that's good. I do however get an error now saying the column doesn't exist event though the column name highlighted does definitely exist. I assume case sensitivity wont be an issue?

Comment: Surely it may be an issue, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899625/1995738) or [Identifiers and Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the docs.